# How to rename a file in blob storage by using Azure Datalake Gen2 Rest API

Tags: azure-storage, file-rename, azure-data-lake

I've try to do the following instruction of this document : [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create)

I used SAS authentication and added this to request header "x-ms-rename-source" but i kept getting this error "403-AuthorizationPermissionMismatch". Doing fine with all others api method but this one seem really tricky. Does anyone have success rename a file or directory with this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using SAS [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1), i used authorization headers. You can check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/common/storage-rest-api-auth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fqueues%2Ftoc.json).

My request headers :

```
  DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
  requestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
  requestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2018-11-09");

  //your source path you want to rename
  requestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-rename-source", renameSourcePath);

  //rename operation only accept authorize by shared key via header
  requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper.GetAuthorizationHeader(
  StorageGen2AccountName, StorageGen2AccountKey, now, requestMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename the file in Blob Storage by using [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/) tool

[image]

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.

Comment: thank you but that's not what i want. I want to use Gen2 Rest API to rename, not by using Storage Explorer.

Comment: As per the know limitations, we could only rename file  through Azure Storage tool for now.